# Почему установка через npm install длится бесконечно?

Tags: npm

Пытаюсь установить bower `npm install -g bower`. Установка длится бесконечно и без ошибок.

```
node --version
v4.2.1

npm --version
2.14.7
```

Другие пакеты также не устанавливаются.

```
"npm install http-server" - также бесконечно
```

Гугление бросает на случаи с ошибками, либо на пакеты с названиями infinity.

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: проверьте всё ли нормально с ресолвингом доменных имён

Comment: Предположительно проблема возникла из-за того, что во время первой установки node выключили электричество.

Comment: Переустанови nodejs.

Comment: Переустанавливал несколько раз, чистил временные и npm папки. Пропатчил npm до 3.3.10. Ничего не помогло.